# What is this insect in Southern Colorado?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

We have found this insect in a bit of a swarm on a concrete pad and on some insulation next to and around our greenhouse in which we have tomato plants.

The insect is about 2mm wide at its widest, and 4mm long at its longest.

What is it?

[image]
[image]